# How best to test CDMA signal when I don't have access to CDMA network?

Tags: android, android-emulator, cdma

I live in the UK and, as far as I know, we don't have CDMA here.

I'm developing an app that reads the signal strength. GSM is not a problem but without a means of testing on my phone or the emulator, the only way I can see of testing CDMA is to release a public alpha with a request for testing feedback.

Has anybody else tackled this problem?

**edit** 181111:
The best answer (the *only* answer) so far is to offer it for testing on oDesk. I don't know whether that answer was removed by the author or a demigod, but other than that my only gain so far is a tumbleweed sticker. *Someone* out there must have had a need for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silence. No real answer - I suppose that the atlantic is too great a gulf for experience to drift across.

I released the app and noted that out of 5,000 downloads there were only two errors. This would appear to coincide with downloaders who didn't read the statement that it would not work with CDMA. One of the phones in question was only released in CDMA form.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, 3g coverage in the UK is wcdma.  GSM is 2g